# Bash: which <app> returns different location than expected

Tags: bash, macos

Can anyone explain to me why the following is happening?

```
[$] pip
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory
[$] which pip
/bin/pip
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Application lookups are cached. Reset the `pip` entry:

```
hash pip
```

Quoting `man bash`:

> If the name is neither a shell function nor a builtin, and contains no slashes, bash searches each element of the  PATH for  a  directory containing an executable file by that name.  Bash uses a hash table to remember the full pathnames of executable files (see hash under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).  A full search of the directories in PATH is  performed only  if  the command is not found in the hash table.

and the entry for `hash` in the same documentation:

> `hash [-lr] [-p filename] [-dt] [name]`
>   For  each name, the full file name of the command is determined by searching the directories in $PATH and remembered.

`which` always searches your path regardless of the hash entry.